# Sorting high scores

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I have a program which stores students' names and scores in a text file. I then need to sort this text file in ascending order based on their scores and implement only the top 10 into a table layout panel. I'm not sure what functions to use to accomplish this.

The text file looks like this:

> 10,  claire
>   0,  Alice
>   5,  Bob
>   8,  Sid
>   9,  Dylan
>   1,  Anna
>   6,  Dan
>   3,  Rebecca
>   4,  Blair
>   2,  George
>   7,  Joe

Comment: Well, since this is homework.  I will provide a hint.  Create a class with properties Student and Score.  Read the file and create an object of type class for each line in the file.  Store each object in a List<StudentScore>.  Query the list using Linq and sort, select top 10 and bind to the table layout panel.

Comment: it's not homework it's coursework and I've been stuck on it now for at least  5 hours but how would you do that i'm so confused thank you

Comment: More important than the file layout is how you store it in memory.  I'll guess parallel arrays since schools still think that is an essential skill.

Comment: What part specifically are you having a problem with? Reading the file, how to represent the data in memory, or sorting the data?  Take it step by step.  If this is course work, then the things you did previously should be preparing for this.  Go back and review those topics and try to think about how those same ideas could be applied to this task.

Comment: LOL... will people leave the question alone and stop editing it... all you've done is remove a few commas and incorrectly manipulated the data... this question does NOT represent the original question from the OP... @Alice Hartley   remove the question and ask it again and change you username...

Comment: Yes it was @MathBio who modified the OPs data, can I ask why you did that sir... ? The data posted by the OP  was originally posted as Name, Score (Claire,10) and you changed it to Score, Name (10, claire)

Comment: Well fortunately here is a link to the OP original question as it was posted... http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35560765/1 it clearly shows the data arranged as Name, Score.... while I conceded that it might be a trivial matter, even less important is replacing a 'p' with 'P' in the spelling of Please along with all the other infantile changes that others have made..... I see better examples of bad grammar and spelling made on SO  go uncorrected.

Comment: @Monty It is indeed fortunate that the original question is out there, for the sake of being able to properly address this issue.The linked format is is not the format I encountered - any data was displayed in-paragraph as a horizontal collection of comma-separated values. I have no desire to make `infantile` corrections, upon seeing the source I simply felt it was intended to be displayed vertically. I have no way of explaining the first post's current display, or how I managed to switch the columns - clearly I made some foolish mistake. I was simply trying to help. Sorry to ruffle feathers.

Comment: The question in it's original format was as clear a question as I have seen on SO [horizontal or vertical, the data would still have been.... Name, Score Name, Score Name, Score]. There was no need for it to be edited. However, 3 users rushed to modify it within 1 hour BUT none of them offered a coding solution... The OP didn't come here for a lesson in spelling and grammar,  all you have done is humiliate them by 'correcting' their use of the English language, the only feathers you Paul Roub and whosrdaddy have ruffled is maybe the OP so you need to apologise to her NOT me.

Comment: You're seriously making this big a deal about whether it should be (name,score) or (score,name) and then blowing it up and accusing someone of belittling the OP? @Monty, calm down, man.

Comment: LOL.... if your going to 'make a big deal' and edit someone else's question to simply correct trivial grammar and spelling to your specific hight standards, then as a result, mess up the question altogether because you failed to reproduce it correctly you have to be corrected yourself surly... or, unlike the OP, are they above criticism. LOL you calm down, man...

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is add a TableLayoutPanel to your form. Give it one column and 10 rows and give it a name. I named mine `tlpScores`.

Next, we will step through what you need to do. First, create a class to hold a score object. I called mine `Scores`:

```
Private Class Scores
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Score As Integer
End Class
```

Next, go into the form's `Load` event and read in the scores:

```
' Change "C:\Scores\Scores.txt" to match wherever your file is located
Dim lines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Scores\Scores.txt")
```

This will read the text file into an array. One element per line.

Next, initialize a new empty List to store multiple Scores of our `Scores` object:

```
Dim scores As New List(Of Scores)
```

Next, iterate through each line we read in and parse out the name and score and store it in a `Scores` object and add that object to our list:

```
For Each line As String In lines
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then
        Continue For
    End If
    Dim score As New Scores
    score.Name = line.Split(","c)(1).Trim()
    score.Score = CInt(line.Split(","c)(0))

    scores.Add(score)
Next
```

Next, we can use Linq to sort the list and take only the top 10:

```
' Your question said Ascending, but I'm assuming you want the top 10.
' If you truly did mean ascending, then change OrderByDescending to
' OrderBy
Dim topTenScores = scores.OrderByDescending(Function(z) z.Score).Take(10)
```

Finally, add them to your TableLayoutPanel:

```
For Each score As Scores In topTenScores
    Dim label As New Label
    label.Text = score.Name & " --> " & score.Score

    tlpScores.Controls.Add(label)
Next
```

Here is the complete program:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\q\scores.txt")
    Dim scores As New List(Of Scores)

    For Each line As String In lines
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        Dim score As New Scores
        score.Name = line.Split(","c)(1).Trim()
        score.Score = CInt(line.Split(","c)(0))

        scores.Add(score)
    Next

    Dim topTenScores = scores.OrderByDescending(Function(z) z.Score).Take(10)

    For Each score As Scores In topTenScores
        Dim label As New Label
        label.Text = score.Name & " --> " & score.Score

        tlpScores.Controls.Add(label)
    Next
End Sub

Private Class Scores
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Score As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Hi this was really useful however with Rebecca's score doesn't appear would you know by any chance why that is?

Comment: @AliceHartley - Not off the top of my head. Are you getting an error or anything?

Comment: no I'm getting no error message or anything to help I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim folder = "<Path to the folder of your Scores.txt file (don't include the file name, just the path up to the folder)>"
    Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ' in the next line replace Scores.txt with the name of your file....
    Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select top 10 * from [Scores.txt] ORDER BY F1 desc", CnStr) ' ORDER BY F1 asc for ascending order
        Try
            Adp.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
End Class
```

This code will select the top 10 results from your *.txt file of scores and display the results in a DataGridView control. I have added the 'ORDER BY F1 DESC' in the SQL statement to sort them in descending order, change DESC to ASC for ascending order..

Seeing as this is coursework you should step though my code, figure out what it's doing and then modify it to suit your needs.... maybe you get an A+.... I'll help you out a little... the 'F1' in the SQL statement is the default column identifier that the OleDbDataAdapter creates because it can't find the column name in the text file....

Looking at the edits made to you question I can see that maybe the score is in the second column of your text file and Name in the first column, so  you will need to change the Order By in the SQL in the code above...

Comment: This answer is inspired :))